# I made new theme directory, why won't it show up in admin GUI?

Tags: themes, admin

I did this:

```
cd wp-content/themes
cp -R someTheme newTheme
```

then:

```
cd newTheme
vim style.css #changed name of theme in the css comment header
```

and then logged into `example.com/wp-admin`. But when I looked at the list of themes (under the appearance header in left menu), I did not see it there. What else must I do for wordpress to notice my theme?

wp version = 3.0.4

Comment: I have multi-site enabled. See my answer below

Answer (score 1):

I have Multi-Site enabled.

That means I must first log in as a super admin, then go to "super admin" > "themes" option in left menu (inside wp-admin), and then enable it there first.

Answer (score 0):

Your theme needs at least an index.php file for WP to recognize it, along with the style.css file. The style.css file doesn't technically need the name, author, etc., WP will use the directory name if it's missing.